# PHP MySQL Json data saving

Tags: php, json

I have a data in my database as I left it below. I want new data to be added to [] in this field, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

the "uyeler" field in the "birlikler" table

```
[{"kullanici":"matta","rutbe":"11","karakteradi":"Meni_Test"},{"kullanici":"test","rutbe":"20","karakteradi":"Vita"}]
```

The code below works fine if the "uyeler" column doesn't have [], but I can't run foreach without [].

```
$sorgum = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM birlikler WHERE id = 1", $vtbaglan);
$sorgu = mysql_fetch_array($sorgum);

$uyelerim = $sorgu['uyeler'];
$uyesim = json_decode($uyelerim, true);


foreach($uyesim as $bubirtest){
    echo ''.$bubirtest['kullanici'].'<br>';
}
echo ''.$uyebilgileri.'

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="kullaniciadi" placeholder="kullaniciadi"s>
    <input type="text" name="rutbe" placeholder="rutbe">
    <input type="text" name="kadi" placeholder="karakteradi">
    <button type="submit" name="verigir">verigir</button>
</form>';
if(isset($_POST["verigir"])){
    $kullaniciadi = $_POST["kullaniciadi"];
    $rutbe = $_POST["rutbe"];
    $karakteradi = $_POST["kadi"];
    $arr = [
        'kullanici' => ''.$kullaniciadi.'',
        'rutbe' => ''.$rutbe.'',
        'karakteradi' => ''.$karakteradi.''
    ];

    $arrim = json_encode($arr);

    //echo '<br>'.$uyeler.','.$arrim.'';

    $veriekle = mysql_query("UPDATE birlikler SET uyeler =  '$uyelerim,$arrim' WHERE id = 1", $vtbaglan);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the obsolete `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued in PHP 5.5 (2013) and removed entirely in PHP 7 (2015). No apps should still be using it. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` (both released in the 2000s!) as soon as possible, and learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Also, if you are running `mysql_` queries successfully, it shows you are running an unsupported version of PHP. You should upgrade your PHP version urgently to continue to receive security updates. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: @ADyson , Thank you for your sensitivity. I'm not coding software that can be hacked. I'm testing something for fun. PHP8's complexity is not for me :/

Comment: Do you want to add a new object to that array of objects or to replace them all with a new array of objects

Comment: @RiggsFolly , I want to add a new data.

Comment: @BurakCanAkpolat PHP8 isn't "complex", it's just a little bit stricter in places. It actually makes it easier to write PHP by stopping you from making some silly mistakes. 99% of it is backwards-compatible though. There is no point living in the past, though - it's not sustainable, at least not in the software world. You can read https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php for a summary of what's changed, and what you may or may not need to be concerned about. There's also a detailed migration guide: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.php. Empower yourself to upgrade by gaining knowledge!

Comment: Anyway, if you want to add data to something you need to get hold of the JSON from the original, decode it, and then add the item to the decoded object, and then re-encode the whole thing as a single JSON entity. You seem to be creating a completely new, separate JSON and then concatenating it with the old one like a string...that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ADyson said, you need to get the current state of that column, convert it to an array of objects, add the new object and then write that back to the database

```
// change the connection to use the MYSQLI extension, then you can freely update to PHP 8
$vtbaglan = new mysqli('localhost', 'userid', 'password', 'database name');

// get the current row from the DB
$sorgum = $vtbaglan->query($vtbaglan, "SELECT * FROM birlikler WHERE id = 1");
$sorgu  = $sorgum->fetch_assoc($sorgum);

$uyesim = json_decode($sorgu['uyeler']);

if(isset($_POST["verigir"])){
    $arr = [
        'kullanici' => $_POST["kullaniciadi"],
        'rutbe' => _POST["rutbe"],
        'karakteradi' => $_POST["kadi"]
    ];

    // add new data to the existing data
    $uyesim[] = $arr;

    // update it back to the database
    $stmt = $vtbaglan->prepare("UPDATE birlikler SET uyeler = ? WHERE id = 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', json_encode($uyesim));
    $stmt->execute();
    
}

// this will now show the new data, if you have added it, as the add code
// now happens before you re-present the page after the update

foreach($uyesim as $bubirtest){
    echo $bubirtest['kullanici'] . '<br>';
}
echo $uyebilgileri.'

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="kullaniciadi" placeholder="kullaniciadi"s>
    <input type="text" name="rutbe" placeholder="rutbe">
    <input type="text" name="kadi" placeholder="karakteradi">
    <button type="submit" name="verigir">verigir</button>
</form>';
```

See there is nothing frightening about using the `mysqli_` OR `PDO` database access extension. These are also available in the old version of PHP you must be using, but now you can updgrade to newer version and this code should not need changing.

Comment: So how can I delete data?