# Deleting mysql json data in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am sharing my codes below with you. I can save new data as json in my database, but I couldn't figure out how to delete what I want from this data. How should I do?

```
<?php
include("matta/database.php");
?>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<?php 
$sorgum = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM birlikler WHERE id = 1", $vtbaglan);
$sorgu = mysql_fetch_array($sorgum);

$uyelerim = $sorgu['uyeler'];
$uyesim = json_decode($uyelerim, true);


foreach($uyesim as $bubirtest){
    echo ''.$bubirtest['kullanici'].'<br>';
}
echo ''.$uyebilgileri.'

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="kullaniciadi" placeholder="kullaniciadi"s>
    <input type="text" name="rutbe" placeholder="rutbe">
    <input type="text" name="kadi" placeholder="karakteradi">
    <button type="submit" name="verigir">verigir</button>
</form>';
if(isset($_POST["verigir"])){
    $kullaniciadi = $_POST["kullaniciadi"];
    $rutbe = $_POST["rutbe"];
    $karakteradi = $_POST["kadi"];
    $arr = [
        'kullanici' => ''.$kullaniciadi.'',
        'rutbe' => ''.$rutbe.'',
        'karakteradi' => ''.$karakteradi.''
    ];
    $uyesim[] = $arr;
    $arrim = json_encode($uyesim);

    //echo '<br>'.$uyeler.','.$arrim.'';

    $veriekle = mysql_query("UPDATE birlikler SET uyeler =  '$arrim' WHERE id = 1", $vtbaglan);
}
?>
```

my previous question: [PHP MySQL Json data saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320278/php-mysql-json-data-saving)

Edit:

I tried the code stated by @gguney but could not reach the result. I leave the "uyeler" column in my database below so that I can clearly explain the way I want.

```
[{"kullanici":"matta","rutbe":"20","karakteradi":"Vitality_Test"},{"kullanici":"Linuxy","rutbe":"19","karakteradi":"Linuxy_Test"}]
```

To give an example of the operation I want to do; I want to delete the user whose "kullanici" value is "matta" from this line. In other words, I want the new data that I want to reach as a result of my operation to be as follows;

```
[{"kullanici":"Linuxy","rutbe":"19","karakteradi":"Linuxy_Test"}]
```

The PHP version I'm using is a bit old. I'm aware of this, but I have to use this version for my current job. I would be very grateful if you could help.

Comment: You could use `unset($array[index])` on your array before encoding it, and save that into your database

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 (2013), and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0 (2015). Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

You can update that json field. Or like any other array field. Just use **unset**.

For example:

```
unset($arr['rutbe']);
```

and use again your update mysql query to delete that field.

Or you can use MySQL JSON_REMOVE function

```
UPDATE birlikler
SET birlikler.uyeler = JSON_REMOVE(birlikler.uyeler, 'rutbe');
```